# Unix: One line bash command to merge 3 files together. extracting only the first line of each

Tags: bash, file, sed, merge

I am having time with my syntax here:
I have 3 files with various content file1 file2 file3 (100+ lines). I am trying to merge them together, but only the first line of each file should be merged. The point is to do it using one line of bash code: 
`sed -n 1p file1 file2 file3` returns only the first line of file1

Comment: Almost there if using Gnu sed; `sed -ns '1p' file{1,2,3}`

Answer (score 6):

You might want to try 
`head -n1 -q file1 file2 file3`.

Comment: Although this is the best way to do it, I think the OP is asking for `sed` specifically.

Comment: @bitmask: That's not how I am reading the question. I think the OP is asking how "to do it using one line of bash code", and `sed` is just an example. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if by merge you mean concatenate or join?

In `awk` by joining *(each first line in the files printed side by side)*:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{printf "%s ",$0}'  file1 file2 file3
1 2 3
```

In `awk` by concatenating *(each first line in the files printed one after another)*:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1'  file1 file2 file3
1
2
3
```

Comment: @user2180912 you should accept which ever answer helped you most. You do this by clicking the tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: sudo_O what does the FNR part stand for in the awk line ?

Comment: `FNR` is the `awk` variable that stores the current record number in current file *(default records are lines)* .

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `head` as explained by [themel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529618/430766)'s answer. However, if you insist in using `sed` you cannot simply pass all files to it, since they are implicitly concatenated and you lose information about what the first line is in each file respectively. So, if you really want to do it in sed, you need bash to help you out:

```
for f in file1 file2 file3; do sed -n 1p "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid calling external processes by using the `read` built-in command:

```
for f in file1 file2 file3; do read l < $f; echo "$l"; done > merged.txt
```